How to evaluate this conditional expectation for the E-step in expectation-maximisation?
I'm trying to devise an expectation-maximisation algorithm for a certain problem but I'm unable to derive the conditional expectation in the E-step. For the purpose of this question I'll simplify the problem and discard unnecessary details.
Suppose that

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables with known multivariate normal distributions (originally denoting latent and observed data, respectively).
$Y = AX$ where $A$ is a known, singular matrix.
$X = \begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2\end{bmatrix}$.

Then, how does one approach finding the expression for $\mathbb{E}_{X \vert Y} \left[ ||X_1 - m_1 ||_{C_1^{-1}}^2 \right] $ where $m_1$ and $C_1$ are the mean and covariance of $X_1$, respectively?
Here's my attempt:
$$ \begin{align} \mathbb{E}_{X \vert Y} \left[ ||X_1 - m_1 ||_{C_1^{-1}}^2 \right] &= \int ||X_1 - m_1 ||_{C_1^{-1}}^2 p(x \vert y) dx \\
&= \int ||X_1 - m_1 ||_{C_1^{-1}}^2 \frac{p(y \vert x) p(x)}{p(y)} dx \end{align} $$
$p(x)$ and $p(y \vert x)$ are known of course, but this expression is extremely tedious to compute. Is there not a more simple and elegant approach? Otherwise, how does one tackle the resulting integral (which includes a complicated exponential term)?
